# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2151 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinBasePlugin

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinBasePlugin

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1